# DirectX 12 device suspended immediately after creation

Tags: directx, directx-12

I am getting a strange error when creating the DirectX 12 command queue.
Other DX12 applications are able to launch successfully on the same machine.

My computer uses the `D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_0` `if` block.
The graphics card used for testing is NVIDIA GT 740, with 361.75 drivers

This is the code in use (minimized):

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <d3d12.h>
#include <dxgi1_4.h>
#include <comdef.h>
#include <D3d12sdklayers.h>
#include <string>

#pragma comment(lib,"d3d12.lib")
#pragma comment(lib,"dxgi.lib")
#pragma comment(lib,"d3dcompiler.lib")
using namespace std;

LRESULT WINAPI WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    switch (msg)
    {
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
    }
}
int WINAPI wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    LPTSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow) {
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(hPrevInstance);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(nCmdShow);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lpCmdLine);

    wchar_t* WindowClass = L"Papergate";
    WNDCLASSEX wc;
    ZeroMemory(&wc, sizeof(WNDCLASSEX));

    wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wc.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 2);
    wc.lpszClassName = WindowClass;

    if (!RegisterClassEx(&wc))
    {
        return 1;
    }

    HWND hwnd = CreateWindowEx(NULL, wc.lpszClassName, WindowClass,
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
        NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

    if (!hwnd)
    {
        UnregisterClass(WindowClass, hInstance);
        return 1;
    }
    ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_SHOWDEFAULT);
    UpdateWindow(hwnd);

    ID3D12Device* device;
    HRESULT result = D3D12CreateDevice(NULL, D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_12_1,
        __uuidof(ID3D12Device), (void**)&device);
    if (FAILED(result))
    {
        result = D3D12CreateDevice(NULL, D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_12_0,
            __uuidof(ID3D12Device), (void**)&device);
        if (FAILED(result))
        {
            result = D3D12CreateDevice(NULL, D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_0,
                __uuidof(ID3D12Device), (void**)&device);
            if (FAILED(result)) {
                _com_error error(result);
                MessageBox(hwnd, error.ErrorMessage(),
                    (wstring(L"Error: ") + to_wstring(__LINE__)).c_str(),
                    MB_OK);
                return 2;
            }
        }
    }

    ID3D12Debug* debugInterface;
    if (SUCCEEDED(D3D12GetDebugInterface(IID_PPV_ARGS(&debugInterface))))
    {
        debugInterface->EnableDebugLayer();
    }

    D3D12_COMMAND_QUEUE_DESC commandQueueDesc;
    commandQueueDesc.Flags = D3D12_COMMAND_QUEUE_FLAG_NONE;
    commandQueueDesc.NodeMask = 0;
    commandQueueDesc.Priority = D3D12_COMMAND_QUEUE_PRIORITY_NORMAL;
    commandQueueDesc.Type = D3D12_COMMAND_LIST_TYPE_DIRECT;
    ID3D12CommandQueue* commandQueue;
    result = device->CreateCommandQueue(&commandQueueDesc, __uuidof(ID3D12CommandQueue), (void**)&commandQueue);
    if (FAILED(result)) {
        _com_error error(result);
        MessageBox(hwnd, error.ErrorMessage(),
            (wstring(L"Error: ") + to_wstring(__LINE__)).c_str(), MB_OK);
        result = device->GetDeviceRemovedReason();
        error = _com_error(result);
        MessageBox(hwnd, error.ErrorMessage(),
            (wstring(L"Error: ") + to_wstring(__LINE__)).c_str(), MB_OK);
        debugInterface->Release(); device->Release(); return 2;
    }

    MSG msg;
    ZeroMemory(&msg, sizeof(MSG));
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0) && msg.message != WM_QUIT)
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    commandQueue->Release();
    device->Release();
    UnregisterClass(WindowClass, hInstance);
    return 0;
}
```

I am getting the following errors on lines 97 and 102, respectively:

```
The GPU device instance has been suspended. Use GetDeviceRemovedReason to determine the appropriate action.
```

Second error:

```
The GPU will not respond to more commands, most likely because some other application submitted invalid commands.
The calling application should re-create the device and continue.
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems quite likely to be a driver bug of some kind. Check to see if there are updated drivers for your hardware. You should try using the Direct3D12 Game templates in this [VSIX](https://github.com/walbourn/directx-vs-templates/raw/master/VSIX/Direct3DUWPGame.vsix) and see if they hit the same kind of issue (for more details on the templates see [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2015/12/17/direct3d-game-visual-studio-templates-redux.aspx)).

Your cascade pattern of calling `D3D12CreateDevice` for various feature levels is unusual and is not necessary. If your application can run on Direct3D Feature Level 11.0 or greater, then just use `D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_0` once. You should pass whatever your *minimum* supported feature level is to this function.

If the Direct3D 12 device does support a higher feature level, you can discover that by using [CheckFeatureSupport](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn788653.aspx) either by checking for the individual features or by using `D3D12_FEATURE_FEATURE_LEVELS`:

```
// Create the DX12 API device object.
DX::ThrowIfFailed(D3D12CreateDevice(
    adapter.Get(),
    m_d3dMinFeatureLevel,
    IID_PPV_ARGS(&m_d3dDevice)
    ));

// Determine maximum supported feature level for this device
static const D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL s_featureLevels[] =
{
    D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_12_1,
    D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_12_0,
    D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_1,
    D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_0,
};

D3D12_FEATURE_DATA_FEATURE_LEVELS featLevels =
{
    _countof(s_featureLevels), s_featureLevels, D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_0
};

HRESULT hr = m_d3dDevice->CheckFeatureSupport(D3D12_FEATURE_FEATURE_LEVELS,
    &featLevels, sizeof(featLevels));
if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
{
    m_d3dFeatureLevel = featLevels.MaxSupportedFeatureLevel;
}
else
{
    m_d3dFeatureLevel = m_d3dMinFeatureLevel;
}
```

Keep in mind that `D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_12_0` and `D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_12_1` are essentially just `D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_1` with a few optional features made mandatory. If your app is already checking for them at 11.x then there's no reason to 'require' 12.0 or 12.1. See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476876.aspx).

For the vast majority of Direct3D 12 games & applications, `D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_0` or `D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_1` are good choices. Keep in mind that while AMD/ATI supported Feature Level 11.1 pretty early, NVIDIA DirectX 11 parts only supported 11.0 with some optional features for some time.

Comment: My reasoning with the if tree was that newer feature levels might have better driver support than legacy levels, so they might perform a little better.

The example you gave works, I am now trying to figure out why it works and mine doesn't.

Comment: The device is the same no matter what feature level you request. The only reason you'd want to know if the device supported a higher feature level is so your application can use features of the API that require it. The ``CheckFeatureSupport`` check tells you that.